# MATLAB - multiple plots with advanced settings

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm getting the "String argument is an unknown option." error for the following command:

> ```
>            plot(x,data1,'-mo',...
>             'LineWidth',2,...
>             'MarkerEdgeColor','k',...
>             'MarkerFaceColor',[.49 1 .63],...
>             'MarkerSize',10,...
>             x,data2,'-bs',...
>             'LineWidth',2,...
>             'MarkerEdgeColor','k',...
>             'MarkerFaceColor',[.49 1 .63],...
>             'MarkerSize',10)
> ```

Interestingly the following two work without a problem:

> ```
>            plot(x,data1,'-mo', x, data2, '-bs');
>
>            plot(x,data1,'-mo',...
>             'LineWidth',2,...
>             'MarkerEdgeColor','k',...
>             'MarkerFaceColor',[.49 1 .63],...
>             'MarkerSize',10)
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why is because you can only specify the flags for changing attributes of your plot **once** per `plot` call.  As such, when you start using `x` and `data2`, and you start defining subsequent attributes, you will get an undefined error.  If you want to plot both of these at the same time, consider using two separate `plot` calls, and using `hold on` to ensure that subsequent calls to `plot` do not clear the figure.  As such:

```
figure;    
plot(x,data1,'-mo', 'LineWidth',2, 'MarkerEdgeColor','k',...
        'MarkerFaceColor',[.49 1 .63] 'MarkerSize',10);
hold on;
plot(x,data2,'-bs','LineWidth',2, 'MarkerEdgeColor','k',...
        'MarkerFaceColor',[.49 1 .63], 'MarkerSize',10);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please care to elaborate which attributes cause the problem aka I can't define more than once per plot call?

Comment: @alexT - The `LineWidth`, `MarkerEdgeColor`, `MarkerFaceColor` and `MarkerSize`.  The style of the points (connectedness, point styles like `x`, `o`, etc. are OK to be defined multiple times.  In your case that's `-mo` and `-bs`.  You're very welcome btw and welcome to StackOverflow!